# Getting the day number based on a range of dates in a reference table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a "Data Table Range" table see attached that tells me the date range and how many total days in between the dates.  I have a second data table that will have random dates say 02/05/2019, 04/07/2019 and 07/06/2019 but how would I approach in SQL to get the corresponding Day of that range for example for a DaysField?

Example:

```
Date        DaysField(according to ref table attached)
02/05/2019  3
04/07/2019  1
07/06/2019  35
```

[image: Date Table Range]

Answer (score 1):

You would use `join` and `datediff()`:

```
select t2.*,
       datediff(day, dr.startdate, t2.date) as daysdiff
from table2 t2 join
     daterange dr
     on t2.date >= dr.startdate and t2.date <= dr.enddate;
```